# The order of $H = \{X \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p) \mid \det(X) = 1\}$ with the definition

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Let be a prime $p$ and $H = \{X \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p) \mid \det(X) = 1\}$. I know that the order of a element $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is the less $k$ such that $g^k = e$, but I don't understand how to use this to find the order of H.

Comment: That's two different meanings of the term "order." This is asking for $|H|$.  Apply the first isomorphism theorem to the determinant map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first isomorphism theorem states that if you have a group morphism $f:G\longrightarrow G'$ then it induces an isomorphism $G/{\rm Ker}(f)\overset{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}{\rm Im}(f)$. Applying this to $\det:{\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)\longrightarrow\mathbf{F}_p^*$ gives you an isomorphism ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)/H\overset{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf{F}_p^*$ because $H={\rm Ker}(\det:{\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)\longrightarrow\mathbf{F}_p^*)$ and $\det$ is surjective. This means that
$$ p-1=|\mathbf{F}_p^*|=|{\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)/H|=\frac{|{\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)|}{|H|}=\frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{|H|} $$
therefore $|H|=p(p^2-1)$.

Comment: Why is $|\text{GL}_2(\mathbf F_p)|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$?

Comment: @Nothingspecial There are $p^2-1$ possibilities for the first row (you can chose any non-zero vector in $\mathbf{F}_p^2$) and there are $p^2-p$ possibilities for the second row because you have to chose it in $\mathbf{F}_p^2\setminus\mathbf{F}_pv$ where $v$ is the first row.

Comment: Makes sense..! However, is there an explicit formula for $|\text{GL}_n(\mathbf F_p)|$ in general?

Comment: Yes, the same reasoning gives
$$ |{\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)|=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^k)=(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\cdots (p^n-p^{n-1}). $$

Comment: I learned from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399412/955582) that this formula works for any finite field... (Just we replace $p$ by $p^i$...) I have never had so much realization from a simple comment I made... Thank you for helping me with my curiosity!